# Scala claims I am using different versions of Akka

Tags: scala, akka

[View repository at this specific commit here](https://github.com/gardncl/scala-sputnik-scraper/tree/e3638b5cdbc24f6a1bcf03d540dae184232b05ca)

I'm putting together a small SBT project and to learn how to use akka actors. I was able to get a simple example working with just akka, but as soon as I use an external library things stop working. I get a very large stack trace with this

```
objc[15196]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10cc6c4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10ccf84e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Detected java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which MAY be caused by incompatible Akka versions on the classpath. Please note that a given Akka version MUST be the same across all modules of Akka that you are using, e.g. if you use akka-actor [2.5.8 (resolved from current classpath)] all other core Akka modules MUST be of the same version. External projects like Alpakka, Persistence plugins or Akka HTTP etc. have their own version numbers - please make sure you're using a compatible set of libraries.                 
Uncaught error from thread [HelloSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]: akka.actor.ActorCell.addFunctionRef(Lscala/Function2;)Lakka/actor/FunctionRef;, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for for ActorSystem[HelloSystem]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorCell.addFunctionRef(Lscala/Function2;)Lakka/actor/FunctionRef;
```

My dependencies look like this:

```
  object v {
    val akka = "2.5.8"
    val scrape = "0.4.0"
  }

  val akka = Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % v.akka,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % v.akka
  )

  val scrape = Seq(
    "io.bfil" %% "scalescrape" % v.scrape
  )

  lazy val allDeps =  akka ++ scrape
```

I am using [this library](https://github.com/bfil/scalescrape) that also uses akka version `5.8` so what gives? Where could this conflicting version of akka actor be coming from? Here is my `build.sbt` that includes the conflict manager I attempted using:

```
import Dependencies._

name := "sputnik-scraper"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

conflictManager := ConflictManager.strict

dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.8"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= allDeps
)
```

EDIT: Added code from main.

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import io.bfil.scalescrape.actor.ScrapingActor

object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  // default Actor constructor
  val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleScraper], name = "helloactor")
  helloActor ! "hello"
  helloActor ! "buenos dias"
}


class ExampleScraper extends ScrapingActor {

  private val baseUrl = "https://www.sputnikmusic.com/"

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _       => grabMainTitle(baseUrl)
  }

  private def grabMainTitle(url: String) =
    scrape {
          get(url) { response =>
            complete(doIt(response))
          }
    }

  private def doIt(response: Any): Unit = {
    println(response)
  }
}
```

Comment: if possible could you provide the actor and the main program here

Comment: I added the code to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly good chance it's caused by Akka-HTTP version 10.0.1 used in [scalescrape](https://github.com/bfil/scalescrape/blob/master/build.sbt) being out of sync with Akka 2.5.  Here's the release note of the more recent [Akka-HTTP 10.0.5](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/release-notes/10.0.x.html#10-0-5):

> This is the fifth maintenance release of the Akka HTTP 10.0 series. It
>   is primarily aimed at stability aligning the internals with the
>   upcoming Akka 2.5 release. ...

You might want to consider modifying the Akka-HTTP dependency to a more recent version of Akka HTTP 10.0.  Latest version as of now is 10.0.11.

Comment: How would `scalescrape` work if it contains conflicting versions? Going to try this now.

Comment: It doesn't work. Here is my full repo:
https://github.com/gardncl/scala-sputnik-scraper/tree/e3638b5cdbc24f6a1bcf03d540dae184232b05ca

Comment: I think @chunjef's answer re: explicit Akka Stream dependency is the key to addressing your original problem, although according to this [issue discussion](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1151), it sounds like Akka-HTTP 10.0 may never work seamlessly with Akka 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

From the compatibility guidelines for Akka HTTP 10.0.x (scalescrape 0.4.0 depends on Akka HTTP 10.0.1):

> Akka HTTP 10.0.x is (binary) compatible with *both* Akka `2.4.x` as well as Akka `2.5.x`, however in order to facilitate this the build (and thus released artifacts) depend on the `2.4` series. Depending on how you structure your dependencies, you may encounter a situation where you depended on `akka-actor` of the `2.5` series, and you depend on `akka-http` from the `10.0` series, which in turn would transitively pull in the `akka-streams` dependency in version `2.4` which breaks the binary compatibility requirement that all Akka modules must be of the same version, so the `akka-streams` dependency MUST be the same version as `akka-actor` (so the exact version from the `2.5` series).
>
> In order to resolve this dependency issue, you must depend on akka-streams explicitly, and make it the same version as the rest of your Akka environment....

Change your Akka dependencies to the following:

```
val akka = Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % v.akka,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % v.akka,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % v.akka // <-- add this
)
```

(Note that the [compatibility guidelines](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/compatibility-guidelines.html) for the current 10.1.x branch of Akka HTTP have changed.)

Comment: So this removed that error, but I got another similar one. Is it possible that this repo is simply unusable due to its own internal conflicts? Here is what I get when digging into the scala conflicts:
(sorry this is on pastebin but i dont have enough characters in here)
https://pastebin.com/1SMsBcea

Comment: Those log messages that are at the `[warn]` level are no cause for concern: they indicate that the Akka 2.4.16 jars were evicted in favor of version 2.5.8, which is what you want.